# Android- A textView trouble

Tags: android

i am a quite new android programmer and facing strange error on `TextView`. I want to write a text into `EditText` field and with a `Button`s help, want to show it on a `TextView`. But when i run it on my phone, i put some text and hit the `Button` it changes the `TextView` into this:

"android.widget.EditT
ext{4279e770
VFED..CL..F.....
.......... app:id/
editText}"

```
package com.example.tolgaen.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView monitor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            monitor.setText(input.toString());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

It does not give any error message on logcat and i cannot figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the getText () method to obtain an Editable object that you can transform a string using toString ()

```
monitor.setText(input.getText());
```

If you need the text as string should be

```
String str = input.getText().toString();
```

Comment: toString is not necessary because method setText() has CharSequence as parameter

Comment: of course you would have to not use the toString () unless you really need a string